# Datatable width option is not working

Tags: jquery, datatable

jQuery:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                    "columnDefs": [
                        { "width": "1%", "targets": 0 }
                    ]

                });
```

Anyone can please help me why width option is not working. You can check full source code on http://vsss.co.in/Admin/index.php/Area/area_list.

Comment: You need to create a demo example link of your problem so that we can check and rectify. Use stack code editor or jsFiddle.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: maybe check your datatable version. They made a significant changes.

Answer (score 0):

Its one of dataTable plugin issue. Am also facing this. But am handling for html code. So if you really want to fix immediately means go with html control.